# Complex relationships with Doctrine

Tags: doctrine, relational-database, doctrine-1.2

I'm building a platform where visitors can fill out forms to request quotes for products and services in various markets.

Example: visitor John Doe wants to have solar panels installed on his roof. He visits our website, picks his category (solar panels) and fills out the form. His contact details are then sent to all of our solar panel suppliers.

All categories for which quotes can be requested are stored in a `category` table:

```
id | name
-------------------
1  | solar panels
2  | car rental
```

Every category has 2 forms that need to be filled out:

1. One form with contact details of the visitor and for which category they want to receive quotes. This form has the same fields for every category and is stored in an `inquiry` table:

   ```
   id | fk_id_category | name     | email              | Region
   ----------------------------------------------------------
   1  | 1              | John Doe | johndoe@gmail.com  | New York
   2  | 2              | Jane Doe | janedoe@gmail.com  | California
   ```
2. One form with specific questions related to that category. These are stored in a `category_field` table:

   ```
   id | fk_id_category | label
   ---------------------------------------------------------------
   1  | 1              | What type of roof do you have?
   2  | 2              | What type of car do you want to rent?
   3  | 2              | For how long do you want to rent the car?
   ```

   The answers to those questions are stored in an `inquiry_detail` table:

   ```
   id | fk_id_inquiry | fk_id_category_field | answer
   ---------------------------------------------------------------
   1  | 1             | 1                    | A flat roof
   2  | 2             | 2                    | An SUV
   3  | 2             | 3                    | One week
   ```

I'm using Doctrine 1.2.4 and I want to find out how to save the category-specific answers (those in the `inquiry_detail` table).

Currently I have the following solution, but I think there should be a better way: set the `name` attribute of each form element to the `id` of its corresponding record in the `category_field` table:

```
<label for="2">What type of car do you want to rent?</label>
<input type="text" name="2" />
<label for="3">For how long do you want to rent the car?</label>
<input type="text" name="3" />
```

Upon submission of a form we iterate over the `$_POST` array and create a new `inquiry_detail` record for each element (don't mind the `fk_id_inquiry` for now).

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $inquiryDetail = new Model_Inquiry_Detail();

    $inquiryDetail['fk_id_category_field']   = $key;
    $inquiryDetail['answer']                 = $value;

    $inquiryDetail->save();
}
```